# org-babel shell always binds to "fish"

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have the excellent `fish` shell set as the default shell on my main laptop. For portability reasons (and editability reasons, as editing fish shell source blocks is buggy and slow) I'd still like to sometimes use `sh` or `bash` in my `org-mode` source blocks. It seems that org always resolves to `fish`, no matter what I try:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo $SHELL
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /usr/bin/fish

#+BEGIN_SRC bash
echo $SHELL
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /usr/bin/fish

#+BEGIN_SRC fish
echo $SHELL
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /usr/bin/fish

#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo $SHELL
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /usr/bin/fish
```

`org-babel-shell-names` is set to `("sh" "bash" "zsh" "fish" "csh" "ash" "dash" "ksh" "mksh" "posh")`. How do I debug this? Or is there any way to set the shell to bash globally for `org-babel`? I'm using emacs 26.3 with the spacemacs configuration at commit `5fcd84d84` and latest org-mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that the `SHELL` environment variable isn't what you think it is.

Try echoing `$0` instead -- or running any built-in shell command which will give shell-specific output (bash has a `help` command, for example).